# Advanced routing with firewall marks and `rp_filter`

Tags: linux, routing

Today is routing day. You should now how to add an IP route, basic use of `ip rule`, and good understanding of `iptables` to read this.

This is cross posted (in French) on [LinuxFr](https://linuxfr.org/users/glandos/journaux/routage-avance-avec-marquage-de-paquet-et-rp_filter).

## Problem

I have an ADSL modem (Freebox) in bridge mode, and an optic fibre (Livebox) in DMZ mode.
All but selected traffic goes via ADSL, and the other one goes via fibre channel.
This is my setup, and in the opposite case, the problem will still be the same.

To ease the issue, I'll talk about traffic going through the router, running Debian GNU/Linux, and not about the traffic generated by this router.

My ADSL address is 82.236.xxx.xxx and fibre is 90.76.xxx.xxx.

## What should work

We take for granted that the `mangle` table is empty.

```
> ip route show table livebox
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth_livebox src 192.168.1.253 
82.236.xxx.0/24 dev eth_adsl scope link src 82.236.xxx.xxx 
192.168.0.0/24 dev bridge_local scope link src 192.168.0.253 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth_livebox scope link src 192.168.1.253 

iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING --destination 23.23.114.123 -j MARK --set-mark 1
ip rule add from all fwmark 0x1 lookup livebox
```

This is not working. It means that when I do

```
curl http://api.ipify.org/ --resolve api.ipify.org:80:23.23.114.123
```

from a LAN client, nothing is returned.

## What works

The `livebox` table is unchanged.
However, after flushing the `mangle` table, we fill it with this:

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING --source 23.23.114.123 -j TOS --set-tos 0x10
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING --destination 23.23.114.123 -j TOS --set-tos 0x10
ip rule add from all tos 0x10 lookup livebox
```

And then :

```
> curl http://api.ipify.org/ --resolve api.ipify.org:80:23.23.114.123
90.76.xxx.xxx
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Why?

Between the two snippets, I changed two things:

1. I used the [TOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_of_service) IP header instead of firewall marked, managed internally by the kernel and its modules.
2. I marked the returning packets.

### I lied (by omission): `rp_filter`

I forgot to say that on all interfaces, the `rp_filter` is set to 1.
According to the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt), the value 1 stands for a strict reverse path checking as defined in the [RFC 3704](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3704#section-2.2).

To summarize, when a packet comes into an interface, the kernel swap both `source` and `destination` IP address fields, and try to route this new fake packet. If the chosen route goes out through the interface where the packet comes from, the check is ok. Otherwise, the packet is dropped.

So, according to `What should work`, since the incoming packet is not marked with `1`, the strict reverse path checking fails. Indeed, the returning packet comes through `eth_livebox`, but without mark, it is routed according to the `main` table, which says to go through `eth_adsl`. It is a failure. This is the reason of the change no. 2.

### Why TOS and not MARK ?

Yes, of course, I tried `-j MARK` on returning packets. And this is not working. After some hours of digging old mailing-lists messages, I found [this one](https://lists.debian.org/debian-firewall/2004/10/msg00175.html):

> OK, looking at fib_validate_source(), it looks like how rp_filter
> works is just that the kernel takes the packet, reverses src & dst
> addrs and interfaces, and tries to do a routing lookup.  It totally
> ignores marking when building the routing key, but weirdly enough,
> it does check the TOS.

OOOOOK. So I read some documentation about TOS, and since I'm still looking for a solution, I do it quick and dirty. It works. This is the reason of the change no. 2.

## Can it be better?

I let you check the [code of `fib_validate_source()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/c1d61e7fe3760851319138550efb732273ab2e57/net/ipv4/fib_frontend.c#L412). Honestly, it's too heavy for me.

But in my opinion, the result is inconsistent. I know that `TOS` is inside the `IP` header, and that firewall marks are specific to host internals. And on the other side [`ip rule`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iproute2/ip-rule.8.en.html) has a syntax to look for a route either on the `TOS` header value or on the firewall mark value with `fwmark`.

I don't know what I really should do for now, and here are my conclusions, non exclusive.

### Give up `rp_filter` on public interfaces

The goal of `rp_filter` is to avoid DDoS, but also to filter rogue clients that forge packets directly within my own managed network. It is a bit like [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework), it protects other actors.

On my public interfaces, I obviously have a routing entry like `default via IP`, so anyway, the `rp_filter` will conclude that the packet can be answered. Indeed, if a packet arrives until my router, well it's because my ISP let it through. And they managed to route it.

So I could give up and set `rp_filter` to 0 on all those interfaces (warning: the maximal value between net.ipv4.conf.eth_livebox.rp_filter et net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter is applied).

### EDIT: User `rpfilter` from `iptables`

Someone on LinuxFR brought my attention [to this](https://home.regit.org/2011/08/florian-westphal-moving-rp_filter-into-netfilter/): the `rp_filter` control is deprecated, or at least in an abandoned state. There is indeed a [`rpfilter` module](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iptables/iptables-extensions.8.en.html#rpfilter) for `iptables`, which is the future of it. As an example, taken [from here](https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/secure-use-of-helpers/#using-rpfilter-module):

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -m rpfilter --invert -j DROP
ip6tables -A PREROUTING -t raw -m rpfilter --invert -j DROP
```

It is well integrated in the firewall, it works, and returning packets don't even need to be marked, since they are recognized by their state.

### Report this "bug" to kernel developers

It seems very inconsistent to me, and moreover very badly documented. On one hand, `ip rule` let you make rules that work for incoming packets, but not for returning ones: misbehavior.

But here I am: I don't have the time to get skilled enough to read this code, understand it, and try to fix it.
And I don't even know if there is a good reason for that, like the fact that firewall marks are maybe not available when calling `fib_validate_source`.

But if someone here tells me that it could be reported to someone who cares, or explains, and maybe fix and improve, I will gladly do it.

EDIT: Maybe the documentation of the `rp_filter` parameter should be updated…

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to right direction!
Following your link i found [this line](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/c1d61e7fe3760851319138550efb732273ab2e57/net/ipv4/fib_frontend.c#L351) that means that it checks for [src_valid_mark](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/c1d61e7fe3760851319138550efb732273ab2e57/net/ipv4/devinet.c#L2271) on interface which means you need to set net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark (or interface-specific one) to 1 to make rp_filter respect marks set on this packet when looking up FIB to check routing on.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: And this sysctl setting is totally undocumented. I thank you for finding it, but I don't think I'll use it without knowing every possible details of it…

Comment: Here's the commit about `src_valid_mark` in linux net-next in 2009: [net: restore ip source validation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/davem/net-next.git/commit/?h=v2.6.33&id=28f6aeea3f12d37bd258b2c0d5ba891bff4ec479)